# Product of a List or Array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to find a way to get the product of a List or Array without using  "repeat" or any loop on Kotlin but after some research I couldn't find anything similar.

Something like this in Python would be:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
output: 720
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/reduce.html) in Kotlin.

From the doc:

> Accumulates value starting with the first element and applying
>   operation from left to right to current accumulator value and each
>   element.

```
val list = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

val array = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

list.reduce { acc, i ->  acc * i }  // returns 720

array.reduce { acc, i -> acc * i }  // returns 720
```

Comment: Kotlin's code is almost identical to Python's. Why am I not surprised?

Comment: I suppose `reduce` (or `filter`, `map`, `fold`) are standard names in functional programming [collection pipelines](https://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/reduce.html). And all the languages (python, kotlin, clojure...) use the same names and patterns, which of course is good to avoid confusions.

Comment: Late answer, but I feel reduce is a better candidate for this since we don't want a default value or seed value to begin with.

Comment: `reduce` throws an exception if the list is empty. `fold`, as used in Rafal's answer, will not.

Comment: @FWDekker, does it mean that fold will result in 1 for an empty list?

Comment: @AlexanderItes `fold` requires two arguments. The first is the initial value, the second is the same as in `reduce`. If it helps, you can think of `fold` as prepending the first argument to your list before applying your lambda as in `reduce`. So, to calculate the product, do `list.fold(1) { acc, i -> acc * i }`, and it will return 1 if the list is empty.

Comment: @FWDekker, thank you for explaining. Yet the result of having product of 1 for an empty list may be unexpected and counterintuitive. I would rather expect having 0 product in such a case.

Comment: @AlexanderItes Setting the empty product to 1 is conventional, and is also what happens in List and Python, for example. But if your application needs the empty product to be 0, you can instead write `list.ifEmpty { listOf(0) }.reduce { acc, i -> acc * i }`.

Answer (score 22):

An even simpler solution might be: `(1..6).reduce(Int::times)`

Comment: As also noted in the comments of [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45888466/), `reduce` throws an exception if the list is empty. If your list may be empty, you should instead write `list.fold(1, Int::times)`. And if you want the product of an empty list to be 0 instead of 1, you can write `list.ifEmpty { listOf(0) }.reduce(Int::times)`.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) function

```
val total = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).fold(1, { total, next -> total * next })
```

Comment: This works, but fold is less efficient than reduce. Use fold if a) your starting value is not contained in the collection, or b) the operation involves a type transformation (i.e. the output of the fold is of a different type than the generic type of the collection).

Comment: @UncleBob Why `fold` would be less efficient than `reduce`? Looking at Kotlin's source code, `fold` is a simple for-loop with an accumulator, while `reduce` first creates an `Iterator`, checks for emptiness with `hasNext`, and then does a while-loop over the `Iterator` into an accumulator. If anything, `reduce` is slower than `fold`, though the difference is likely negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
   val array = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
   val product = array.fold(1){acc, i -> acc * i}
   println("The result is: $product")
}
```

This will output the product of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **fold** or **reduce** function. Both will work.

```
    val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    println("Product of list: ${listOfMultiplication(array)}")
    fun listOfMultiplication(array: Array<Int>): Int {
        return array.reduce { total, next ->  total * next }
    }
```

```
    val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    println("Product of list: ${listOfMultiplication(array)}")
    fun listOfMultiplication(array: Array<Int>): Int {
        return array.fold(1) { total, next -> total * next }
    }
```